# unit test case for void @Async method

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, junit5

I need to write unit test case for asynchronous method which doesn't return any value. Which is the best practice to test asynchronous method in spring boot and junit 5

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/test-async-controller-mockmvc/

Answer (score 0):

You can write a normally test, ignoring the async and catching the possible exceptions.

For the test no matter if it's asynchronous, and yes if the code work as expected :)